# ExtJS6 TreeGrid Not Displaying Child Nodes

Tags: treegrid, extjs6

I have a tree grid based on the following code:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        var treeData = [{
            mtype: 'InsDataModel',
            recordid: '1',
            companyname: 'Company 1',
            children:[{           
                mtype: 'PlnDataModel',
                recordid: '1A',
                planname: 'Plan 1A'
            },{
                mtype: 'PlnDataModel',                
                recordid: '1B',
                planname: 'Plan 1B'
            }]
        },{
            mtype: 'InsDataModel',            
            recordid: '2',
            companyname: 'Company 2',
            children: []
        },{
            mtype: 'InsDataModel',            
            recordid: '3',
            companyname: 'Company 3',
            children:[{
                mtype: 'PlnDataModel',                
                recordid: '3A',
                planname: 'Plan 3A'
            },{
                mtype: 'PlnDataModel',                
                recordid: '3B',
                planname: 'Plan 3B'
            },{
                mtype: 'PlnDataModel',                
                recordid: '3C',
                planname: 'Plan 3C'
            },{
                mtype: 'PlnDataModel',                
                recordid: '3D',
                planname: 'Plan 3D'
            },{
                mtype: 'PlnDataModel',                
                recordid: '3E',
                planname: 'Plan 3E'                
            }]
        }];
        Ext.define('InsDataModel',{
            extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
            childType: 'PlnDataModel',
            fields:[
                {name: 'recordid'},
                {name: 'text', mapping:'companyname'}
            ]            
        });
        Ext.define('PlnDataModel',{
            extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
            fields:[
                {name: 'recordid'},
                {name: 'text', mapping:'planname'}
            ]
        });
        Ext.define('InsDataStore',{
            extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
            model: 'InsDataModel',
            proxy:{                
                reader:{typeProperty: 'mtype'}
            },
            data:treeData,            
        });
        Ext.define('InsDataGrid',{
            extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
            store: {
                model: 'InsDataModel',
                proxy:{          
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader:{typeProperty: 'mtype'}
                },
                data:treeData
            },
            title: 'My tree Demo',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 400,            
            height: 600,            
            useArrows: true,
            columns:[{
                text: 'Network',
                dataIndex: 'text',
                flex: 1
            }]
        });               
        var newTree = Ext.create('InsDataGrid').show();
    }
});
```

Which is also located at: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/136t

The problem I am running into is the child nodes will not display the text when the parent node is expanded.  Can someone please take a look at the code and let me know what I am doing incorrectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey Mitchell, My application is working with remote data.  For some reason I could not get the data1.json url to work in fiddle so I decided to make the data local.  The problem does still persist with my remote data.  I assume that this will work with the remote data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapping` as a string requires the reader to read a remote response to build the functions to do the mapping. Also, you should remove `childType` from `InsDataModel` model: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/136u

Comment: Hey Mitchell.  Thanks for the response.  Couple of things.  The data is supposed to be remote (I couldn't get fiddle to work properly with remote data so I used local data). The tree is supposed to be heterogeneous - I will be updating two different models.  I understand that I didn't make that point obvious with the data I was using, but I was trying to be brief in the example.

Comment: @user1532602 I've updated my fiddle to use remote loading of the children and kept your heterogeneous models. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/136u

Comment: Thanks, Mitchell.  Always a huge help!

Comment: Mitch...I'm not sure what the difference is between what you are doing in your code and what I am doing.  Please have a look at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13v1.  Still not showing the child nodes.  Thanks for your help.